# onTouchListener: Convert View to ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have a ArrayList of ImageView's in my Activity-Class and all of them should have the same behavior: As soon as you touch them and move your finger to the right or the left, the x-coordinate of this ImageView should also move.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
    float origin_x = 0;
    float origin_x2 = 0;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
    switch (e.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            origin_x = e.getX();
            origin_x2 = lp.leftMargin;
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            float diff = e.getX()-origin_x;
            System.out.println(diff);

            lp.setMargins((int) (origin_x2+diff), lp.topMargin, 0, 0);
            v.setLayoutParams(lp);
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

But since I can only use the "View"-Object in the ontouch-Method, I have no possibility to find out which ImageView was touched.

Do you know how I should solve this problem?

Comment: If each ImageView gets a separate instance of your `OnTouchListener`, there won't be any overlaps. Also, your question is pretty vague - why do you need to figure out which `ImageView` was touched (you could use `View#getId()` to determine that) if all you're doing is moving a View (which `onTouch` receives).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this question has been asked by me very long time ago - but since it received much clicks and even an upvote recently, I decided to answer it now.

**If you want to move a View** (regardless whether it's an ImageView or any other kind of View), you can use the code from my question post. Setting the `margins` to the `onTouch` `MotionEvent` values will work in `RelativeLayouts`.

However, my question also included **how to find the `View` Object** from the `onTouch`-Event **in an ArrayList of `ImageViews`**.
The answer to that is very simple as well:

```
ArrayList<ImageView> arrList = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
/** ... **/
int keyOfView = arrList.indexOf(v);
```

It doesn't matter if `v` is a `View` object or an `ImageView` object. There is no need to cast from `View` to `ImageView` for the ArrayList lookup, because the reference will stay that same - and that is what's actually being searched in the List: The reference.

However, **if you** (for whatever reason) do **need an `ImageView` from a `View` object** and are **not** sure if all `Views` are actually `ImageView` objects, then you can do something like this:

```
if (v instanceof ImageView) {
     ImageView i = (ImageView) v;
}
```

This way you will not get `cast-errors`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only ever use this touch listener with `ImageView`s you could do something like:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v;
```